# Only one record shows up

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT users.xp, users.clan, clans.name,

SUM(CASE WHEN users.clan = clans.name 
              THEN users.xp 
         END) AS total
FROM users, clans

WHERE users.clan = clans.name
```

Why does this SQL query print out only one record when there are multiple clans and in the clans are several users with xp.
It does print out the correct sum of xp in the given clan that it shows, but I need the rest of the clans.

Comment: Read about GROUP BY (and mysql more generally)

Comment: There must be only 1 record in ```users``` table that has a clan value that matches the ```clans``` table name column...

Comment: @Dragos Irrelevant in the present context

Comment: @Anand No. That's not the case.

Comment: @Anand, cause Op os doing `SUM()` without `group by` which would be sum of all records

Comment: Also, please learn about [Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a group function, mysql will "help" you by aggregating the result into a single row. To get one row per clan, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT clans.name, SUM(users.xp) AS total
  FROM users, clans
 WHERE users.clan = clans.name
 GROUP BY clans.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `SUM()` which is an aggregation (group) function.

> "If you use a group function in a statement containing no GROUP BY
>   clause, it is equivalent to grouping on all rows."

Have a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html